# Elasticsearch query to search only words mentioned more than 3 times in document

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Is it possible to search in elasticsearch if i want certain word to be occurred more than n times.
`For e.g. I want to search for word "Bill Gate" only if "Bill Gate" is present more than 3 times in a document`. I am storing field name as "content" that stores the full text of the story. Within this field I want to search for "Bill Gates" and return only those document that has "Bill Gates" word occurred more than or equal to 3 times.

I need to build query that will be generated dynamically based on no of occurrences user want to search for specific words within the content field.

Also, is there any lucene syntax available to do that.

Meanwhile am using elasticsearch version 6.2

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the use case for returning _only_ X number of matches? Would a user not want to see documents with any matches, with more matches being more relevant?

Comment: @Russ Cam I guess based on your comment I assume it may not be possible to do that in elasticsearch. If so could you please confirm? In one of our exceptional use case our search is quite complicated where user perform multiple search condition including proximity search with span near. The no of words occurrence is one of the use case for us where each document content has list of instructions and they want to search only those instructions that has appeared more than n times in each document.

Comment: I'm not aware of a built in query that can do this. Is `Bill Gates` one term i.e. a shingle, or two terms? It _may_ be possible to do something with a script query, not sure

Comment: @RussCam Cam thanks, if i can search for only "Bill" would still be valid for me. Also the field where am searching "Bill" is analyzed field. trying regexp but still not getting result.

Comment: How it is analyzed?

Comment: Default Standard analyzer for text fields in elasticsearch.

Comment: GET data/_search
  {
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "attachment.content": {
        "value": "((Bill)+?([ .,]+)[ ,.a-zA-Z]*){1,3}"
      }
    }
  }
}  Also I tried the above query its not working in elasticsearch but the regex works perfectly fine in regular expression when used with c# or online tools.

Comment: I would not expect the regexp to work because it's running on terms produced by the analysis chain, not the original source text for the field. If `Bill Gates` ends up tokenized as two separate terms, `bill` and `gates`, then the regexp won't match.